# docker image with sbt: gc log issue

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have created a docker image using sbt-native-packager for my service. When I try to run it, I get following error:

```
$ docker run --name my-service -v ..../logs:/opt/docker/log/ -p 8086:8086 ed3117633c56
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*,heap*:file=/opt/docker/log/gc-my-service.log:time,level,tags:filecount=5:filesize=20M', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[0.000s][warning][logging] Ignoring excess -Xlog options: "filesize=20M"
[0.000s][error  ][logging] Error opening log file '/opt/docker/log/gc-my-service.log': Permission denied
[0.000s][error  ][logging] Initialization of output 'file=/opt/docker/log/gc-my-service.log' using options 'filecount=5' failed.
```

Is there some issue with image or is some parameter missing to run command?